# getAccessTokenAsync() returns error code 13000 for Excel online add in

Tags: xml, excel, office-js

I am creating an Excel content add-in and implementing SSO. Everything works fine when it is running on the desktop client Excel app. It is successfully getting the add-in token and then getting the MSG token. But when I am trying the same thing in Excel online with sideloading, the method getAccessTokenAsync() is returning error code 1300.

```
Error code: 13000
Error name: API Not Supported.
Error message: The identity API is not supported for this add-in.
```

I am logged in to office 365 account from the same tenant which granted the admin consent. 
I have added the following to the manifest:

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="IdentityAPI"/>
  </Sets>   
</Requirements>
```

Also, Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('IdentityAPI', 1.1) is returning true.

The `<WebApplicationInfo>` section looks like the following in the the manifest:

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>{application_GUID}</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:44377/{application_GUID}</Resource>
    <Scopes>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
        <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
        <Scope>sites.readwrite.all</Scope>
        <Scope>user.read</Scope>
        <Scope>files.readwrite.all</Scope>
        <Scope>files.read.write</Scope>
    </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 4/10/18:**
A recent bug was introduced that causes 13000 for Office Online. A fix has been made but not yet deployed.

**Original Answer:**

One known cause of 13000 is that the `<WebApplicationInfo>` section is missing from the manifest or is invalid. Fore more info, see [Troubleshooting SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins) and [Configure the add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#configure-the-add-in).

Comment: I have gone through these links and followed the set up steps closely but can not find what is going wrong. 
I have added the `<WebApplicationInfo>` section in the question for reference. Any clue will be really helpful.

Comment: See if the sample here works for you. (Use the Completed version.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet . If it works, then we can figure out what's different between your Excel Add-in and the sample. Also, install the Fiddler tool or the Charles tool that are mentioned near the top of the Troubleshooting article. See if you can capture the Request and Response when Office tries to get the token from AAD. Also, I assume that the "Id" in your manifest is just a placeholder, right? It should be the GUID of the application.

Comment: Thanks Rick for the update. 
Does this bug also affect the add-ins already published in store? Or is it just affecting the development scenario?
Is there any tentative timeline when we can expect the fix to be available as I have a strong dependency on it?

Comment: @DebJ In the past, fixes to Office Online are usually in production within 2 weeks, often one week; but I cannot promise that will happen this time. I think this would affect store add-ins.

Comment: @DevJ This should be fixed now. Please try it again.

Comment: This is working fine now. Verified. Thank a lot for the updates.